# Codeigniter Can't Link to ID'd Element without new page load

Tags: html, anchor

I have a site running on Codeigniter and I'm trying to link to an element on the page via a link, but when you click the link the page reloads instead of moving to that element.

```
<li>
    <a href="#image-0001"> <img alt="image0001" src="/assets/images/portfolio/photography/thumbs/0001.jpg" />
<span>Pointe</span> </a>
    <div class="lb-overlay" id="image-0001">
        <img alt="image01" src="/assets/images/portfolio/photography/full/0001.jpg" />
            <div>
                <h3>pointe <span>/point/</span></h3>
                <p>Dance performed on the tips of the toes</p>
            </div>
        <a class="lb-close" href="#page">x Close</a>
     </div>
</li>
```

Instead of triggering my CSS animation it takes me to the Site Root (localhost/#image-0001).

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You need to create a link at your destination too, using <a name="image-0001">.  For example  `<a name="image-0001"><img alt="image01" ...></a>`

Answer (score 0):

To move around a page using anchors, the target anchor must have a name, not an href.  For example:

```
<a name="top" /> <!-- this is the target -->
<p>Some really long content</p>
<a href="#top">Go To Top</a> <!-- this goes to the target -->
```

This is not something specific to CodeIgniter though, just basic HTML.